# Check if object is in context entity framework

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

Is it possible to check that an object is in the context  before trying to delete that from context ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something like:

```
var key = myContext.CreateEntityKey("Table", myObject);

if (myContext.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out otherObject))
{
     // delete or edit otherObject
}
```

But you find in /delete from the database, not (just) the context.

Comment: Because you don't post Class or Table names I have to make them up.

Comment: A simple var of the same type as myObject.